# О навязанной жене дракона

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, управление, словосочетания

В самиздате встретила название книги "Навязанная жена дракона".
Может, я и не права, но мне кажется, что тут не совсем верное согласование слов. Если жену дракону навязали, то правильно "Навязанная жена дракону"?
Потому что в моей логике в первом варианте дракон себе жену навязал.

Comment: Это какие-то женские романы без авторов, то ли китайские, то ли еще какие. В стандартном варианте называется "Жена дракона", но по всё видимости существуют в названиях "Навязанная жена дракона", "Фиктивная жена дракона", "Обреченная жена дракона", "Навязанная жена драконьего начальника" и прочие, не знаю какая между ними разница, может быть это вообще одно и тоже)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь все верно:

***Навязанная жена*** (чья? кого?) **дракона.**  Это Р.п.

Если дракону навязали жену, то ее можно назвать ***навязанной женой***.

Сравнить:

Жена, навязанная (кому?) **дракону**.

Навязанная (кому?) **дракону** жена.

Comment: Еще можно дополнить: _Навязанная дракону жена_ — и сказать, что вариант _навязанная жена дракону_ неверен, поскольку не бывает определяемого слова внутри определительного оборота.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что на возникновение этого вопроса, как мне кажется, повлияли две причины.

• Первая
Значение и управление глагола [навязать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/114298/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):
**3.** *кому-чему.* Заставить, принудить принять что-либо против желания, против воли. *Навязать своё мнение собранию. Навязать сыну свою волю.*

И действительно, навязать (кому? Д. п.) дракону.

• Вторая
**Раньше** дательный падеж в сочетаниях со словами *жена, сестра* частенько использовался (да и сейчас иногда "проскакивает"): жена (кому?) — царю, дракону, ему...

*— Но я ***жена ему***! – не выдержала Флайвия* (Л. Ви. Роза для дракона).
*Какая она **жена королю**?* (В. Холт. Неуемный волокита).
*— Я **сестра ему*** (Л. Н. Толстой. Франсуаза (1891)).
***Жена царю** по плоти, / По сердцу я чужая* (С. А. Гедеонов, А. Н. Островский. Василиса Мелентьева (1867)).

• **Сейчас** правильным считается родительный падеж.
Главное слово "жена": жена (кого?) дракона.
А причастие к нему уже "навязывается": жена (какая?) навязанная.

Можно проверить, подставив к "дракону" какое-нибудь определение или просклонять (здесь дательный падеж никак "не пройдёт", только родительный):
*навязанная жена огненного **дракона**, о навязанной жене семиглавого **дракона***.